# How well can hybrid motors be throttled?

Tags: design, engines, engineering, thrust

Pretty self explanatory: down to what percentage can hybrid rocket engines be throttled to? And what fuel / oxidiser combinations allow for the greatest throttling?

I'm planning on using hybrids for a school project, which would rely pretty heavily on thrust control. (This is my first time posting a question; I hope this is the right place! If not, just tell me where to post and I'll move there)

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy Good point. Neither answer cites anything, and they say the opposite. Personally I'd love to hear about a real world example that throttled (if one exists).  My gut feel sides with the "badly" answer.

Answer (score 4):

Badly.

You can throttle hybrid engines quite far down, possibly lower than liquid fuel engines - but it comes at a large cost to efficiency. If you throttle your engine to 50%, you're not getting 50% of thrust at similar ISp. You're getting a hard to determine amount of thrust somewhere around 50% at ISp way worse, likely worse than 50% of max. And at the end of the burn you'll end up with spare oxidizer, running out of solid fuel earlier.

Essentially, you're unable to throttle fuel flow. You regulate oxidizer supply, but your solid fuel is available in full amount at all times. This results in burn in non-stoichiometric ratio, fuel-rich exhaust with plenty of partially unburnt fuel (soot), and usage of fuel higher than in stoichiometric ratio. Never mind lower chamber pressure and temperature will result in serious loss of specific impulse. Fuel gets used up faster than oxidizer, producing far less energy than it could, and you're getting a really lousy performance.

Hybrid motors can be stopped, unlike solid, and can be restarted somewhat easier than liquid, and if you are desperate, you can throttle one as well. But they are very badly suited for throttling.

Comment: Do you have a source? Nothing I'm coming across mentions throttling having a large effect on the stoichiometric ratio.

Comment: @Schlusstein: [Ignition!](https://library.sciencemadness.org/library/books/ignition.pdf), chapter 12 "High Density and the Higher Foolishness", end of page 174.

Comment: I would hesitate to cite a book from 1972 for a discussion of modern rocketry.  Last page, top slide, bottom line: http://seitzman.gatech.edu/classes/ae6450/hybrids.pdf Earlier in the presentation empirical values for n were found to be be ~.75.

Comment: @Schlusstein: ah, additional oxidizer injectors downstream... running oxidizer lines along the combustion chamber, extra regulation mechanism balancing pressure between main and extra injectors, extra injectors right into highest temperature zone, account for gunking them up with combustion products, determine extra supply needed, which is waay non-linear... and OP talks about a school project.

Comment: School projects don't need high performance or good stoichiometric ratios.

Comment: @Schlusstein: And so, the motor will be throttlable - poorly. Smoking, spewing soot. I'm also quite afraid about combustion stability. Say, throttled motor seems to cut off, the test person opens oxidizer valve more, oxidizer gathers in combustion chamber until pressure is sufficient that glowing piece of fuel ignites it, and we have a hard start, or worse.

Comment: You would still have that problem with liquid engines though. At least hybrids tend not to explode.

Comment: @Schlusstein: Liquid engines are a big bundle of problems - but the solution from your paper kills the fundamental advantages of hybrid: simplicity and safety. Even in LF engines you don't draw oxidizer lines along the combustion chamber walls, and you are not forced to inject extra oxidizer down the combustion chamber in hard to determine amounts.  And as for the school project, the solution is simple: don't throttle. 100% power or nothing. It's not like the rocket will be performing precise maneuvers or reaching dangerous MaxQ anyway.

Comment: To be clear, I do have access to metal 3D printing places who are happy to help, so the only thing limiting what I can build is design. SpaceX made a 3D printed bipropellant motor, so I see no reason why I can't make myself an engine using liquid propellants, given I do my research, and have a few iterations in the design - and no, I don't think I will make an engine as good as SpaceX's, but hopefully fairly close ;)

Comment: @SF As I said, my project will really rely on throttling. As well as launching the rocket up to a reasonable height, I want to have it land itself - SpaceX style.

Thanks for all of your replies, this has taught me a lot about where I should be going for my project. I'll be sure to ask more questions here - you guys are very helpful!

Comment: @NikL: Seriously consider monopropellant engine. And while 3D printing is nice, some parts just have to be machined. Injectors, turbines, valves - you simply won't get tolerances/surface/smoothness good enough out of a 3D printer.

Comment: @SF I'm pretty sure SpaceX managed to make an engine that was 100% 3D printed, no lathing or machining (except for polishing the surfaces). Either way, I have access to lathes, CNC routers etc. Are there any propellants for a monoprop engine that aren't toxic and don't need special handling / permissions to use?

Comment: @NikL: I'm fairly sure at the very least bearings of turbopumps and nozzles of injectors are machined. These are things that require micron scale precision, and material properties not attainable with 3D printer. As for propellants - Nitrous oxide. Very popular in amateur rocketry, very few disadvantages other than weak performance.

Comment: There is still time to get the bounty if you hurry and add refs now....

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late to be of any help, but I found an article from Stanford about hybrid rockets.
In the last two paragraphs of the 3rd page, they say that hybrid rockets can be throttled.

[https://web.stanford.edu/~cantwell/AA283_Course_Material/AA283_Course_Notes/AA283_Aircraft_and_Rocket_Propulsion_Ch_11_BJ_Cantwell.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ecantwell/AA283_Course_Material/AA283_Course_Notes/AA283_Aircraft_and_Rocket_Propulsion_Ch_11_BJ_Cantwell.pdf)

> The idea of the hybrid rocket has been known since the first flight in 1933 by Soviet researchers, but wasn’t given serious attention until the 1960’s. The primary motivation was the non-explosive character of the fuel, which led to safety in both operation and manufacture. The fuel could be fabricated at any conventional commercial site and even at the launch complex with no danger of explosion. Thus a large cost saving could be realized both in manufacture and launch operation. Additional advantages over the solid rocket are: greatly reduced sensitivity to cracks and de-bonds in the propellant, better specific impulse, **throttle-ability to optimize the trajectory during atmospheric launch and orbit injection** and the ability to thrust terminate on demand. The products of combustion are environmentally benign unlike conventional solids that produce acid forming gases such as hydrogen chloride.
>
> The hybrid rocket requires one rather than two liquid containment and delivery systems. The complexity is further reduced by omission of a regenerative cooling system for both the chamber and nozzle. **Throttling control in a hybrid is simpler because it alleviates the requirement to match the momenta of the dual propellant streams during the mixing process. Throttle ratios up to 10 have been common in hybrid motors**. The fact that the fuel is in the solid phase makes it very easy to add performance enhancing materials to the fuel such as aluminum powder. In principle, this could enable the hybrid to gain an Isp advantage over a comparable hydrocarbon fueled liquid system. (Emphasis added)

Comment: `+1` In Stack Exchange it's important to either summarize, or use an attributed block quote to explain the information in links. Since links often break over time, this keeps the value of the answer for future readers even if that happens.

Answer (score -1):

They throttle about as well as liquid propellant rockets. You still have one liquid propellant with which you can adjust the flow rate, and the solid propellant isn't going to react without it. You run into the same issues with nozzle expansion as you do with all-liquid rockets.

One issue you can have is ongoing smoldering from atmospheric oxygen if you try to stop completely, but that's seldom something that you want to do.

As with liquid-only rockets you can in principle throttle it down as far as you want but run into significant performance losses (reduced exhaust velocity) as you throttle significantly below the optimum thrust for the engine.

Comment: If the rocket is throttled down to the minimum, the nozzle diameter is much to large for the mass flow of hot exhaust gas. The pressure is much to low and the exhaust velocity is very low. Thus the efficiency is very low.